# Spring false positive circular dependency reported

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Spring reports false positive circular dependency error when the dependency order looks like below

- FactoryBean depends on List  (example AnimalFeeder)
- AnimalFeeder depends on List of Strings.

**Interesting things are**

1. Issue was not observed when the spring instantiation order changes Ie) FactoryBean comes before AnimalFeeder. But the issue was seen when AnimalFeeder comes before FactoryBean.
2. This happens only when FactoryBean is involved. issue was not observed when simple bean class is used instead of FactoryBean.

here is the source code

```
public interface Feeder {
    void feed();
}

public class AnimalFeederImpl implements Feeder {
  private List<String> feedingTypes;
  public AnimalFeederImpl(List<String> feedingTypes) {
    this.feedingTypes = feedingTypes;
  }
  @Override
  public void feed() {
    //feed here
  }
}

public class FeederManager {
  private final List<Feeder> feeders;
  public FeederManager(List<Feeder> feeders) {
      this.feeders = feeders;
  }

  //This method will trigger the feeding for every 4 hours
  public void triggerFeeding() { 
  }
}


public class FeederFactory implements FactoryBean, InitializingBean {
  private List<Feeder> feeders;
  private FeederManager feederManager;
  public FeederFactory(List<Feeder> feeders) {
      this.feeders = feeders;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      feederManager = new FeederManager(feeders);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
    context.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
    context.setConfigLocation("test-application-context.xml");
    context.refresh();
  }
}
```

here is the context file

```
 <bean id="water" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="water"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="animalFeeder" class="org.test.spring.autowire.impl.AnimalFeederImpl" autowire="constructor"/> 
 <bean id="animalFeeder" class="org.test.spring.autowire.impl.AnimalFeederImpl" autowire="constructor"/> 
 <bean id="feederMgr" class="org.test.spring.autowire.impl.FeederFactory" autowire="constructor"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue (which also causes a compilation error in your seemingly incomplete example) is that your `FeederFactory` implements the type `FactoryBean`.

```
public class FeederFactory implements FactoryBean, InitializingBean {
```

When Spring tries to instantiate the `AnimalFeederImpl` bean using its constructor

```
public AnimalFeederImpl(List<String> feedingTypes) {
    this.feedingTypes = feedingTypes;
}
```

it needs to first construct the `List<String>` argument. To do that, it needs to scan the context for beans of type `String`. It knows for sure that `water` is a bean of type `String` because it's declared that way in the XML configuration. It knows for sure that `AnimalFeederImpl` isn't a bean of type `String` because its class type is also declared.

For `FeederFactory`, however, it's a little different. By declaring the class as a subclass of `FactoryBean`, you're telling Spring that this bean can create bean(s) of another type. To find out what type that is, Spring needs to instantiate the `FeederFactory` type and use its `getObjectType` method.

But its instantiation requires Spring to autowire

```
public FeederFactory(List<Feeder> feeders) {
```

which requires it to instantiate `AnimalFeederImpl` which is already in construction and the whole thing fails with a circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Sorry, I was bit lazy to format all the lines, hence only pasted skeleton.